# Is there a way to mix a LISP's macro &optional and &key params?

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

I want to define a LISP macro like `dolist` that lets me define an optional output argument. In the following case study, this macro will be called `doread`. It will read lines from a file and return the number of lines found that way.

```lisp
(let ((lines 0))
  (doread (line file lines)
     ;; do something with line
     (incf lines)))
```

The problem is that getting that `lines` to work in the above macro

I can do what I want with &key , but not with &optional &key (and the &key is needed since I want to control how a file is read; e.g with `read` or `read-line` or whatever).

Now the following works **BUT** to works the wrong way.  Here the `out` argument has to be  a `&key` and not a &optional:

```lisp
;; this way works... 

(defmacro doread ((it f  &key out (take #'read)) &body body)
  "Iterator for running over files or strings."
  (let ((str (gensym)))
    `(with-open-file (,str f)
       (loop for ,it = (funcall ,take ,str nil)
             while ,it do
             (progn ,@body))
       ,out)))

;; lets me define something that reads first line of a file
(defun para1 (f)
  "Read everything up to first blank line."
  (with-output-to-string (s)
    (doread (x f :take #'read-line)
      (if (equalp "" (string-trim '(#\Space #\Tab) x))
        (return)
        (format s "~a~%" x)))))

(print (para1 sometime)) ; ==> shows all up to first blank line
```

What I'd like to do is this is the following (note that `out` has now moved into `&optional`:

```lisp
(defmacro doread ((it f &optional out &key   (take #'read)) &body body)
  "Iterator for running over files or strings."
  (let ((str (gensym)))
    `(with-open-file (,str f)
       (loop for ,it = (funcall ,take ,str nil)
             while ,it do
             (progn ,@body))
       ,out)))
```

and if that worked, I could do something like.

```lisp
(defun para1 (f)
  "Print  everything up to first blank line. 
   Return the lines found in that way"
  (let ((lines 0))
      (doread (x f lines :take #'read-line)
        (if (equalp "" (string-trim '(#\Space #\Tab) x))
            (return)
            (and (incf lines) (format t "~a~%" x)))))
```

but it I use `&optional out` I get

```
 loading /Users/timm/gits/timm/lisp/src/lib/macros.lisp
*** - GETF: the property list (#'READ-LINE) has an odd length
```

Comment: Note that in DOREAD the `f` needs to be `,f`.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot mix `&optional` and `&key` and expect to be able to pass only the keyword arguments. You can however define a syntax
that allow for an optional list of arguments associated with the
source.

For example:

```
(defpackage :so (:use :cl :alexandria))
(in-package :so)

(defmacro do-read ((entry source &optional result) &body body)
  (destructuring-bind (source &key (take '#'read)) (ensure-list source)
    (once-only (take)
      `(loop
          :with ,entry
          :do (setf ,entry (handler-case (funcall ,take ,source)
                             (end-of-file () (loop-finish))))
            (progn ,@body)
          :finally (return ,result)))))
```

The syntax for `DO-READ` could be written as:

```
(DO-READ (ENTRY [SOURCE|(SOURCE &KEY TAKE)] &OPTIONAL RESULT) . BODY)
```

This is not an unusual syntax w.r.t. standard Lisp forms (see `LET`, keyword synax in lambda-lists, `defstruct`, etc.).
You could add more keyword parameters along with `TAKE`.

### Remarks

- In macros, I prefer to emit LOOP keywords as keywords, not symbols
  in the macro's definition package; otherwise, when macroexpanding
  the code, you are likely to get the symbols prefixed by the macro's
  package (i.e. `SO::WITH` instead of `:WITH`), which becomes quickly
  unreadable.
- Returning NIL from `READ-LINE` is fine, but not from `READ`, as NIL could be a successfully read value. In
  general, since `TAKE` is provided by the user, you
  don't know if NIL is an acceptable result or not. That's why I catch
  `END-OF-FILE` instead. In case you want to read from other sources you may also check a secondary return value, or document that they signal a condition too.
- The `ENTRY` variable's scope is extended so that `RESULT` can be
  `ENTRY` itself; in your case, `OUT` could not be equal to `IT`,
  because once you exit the loop, you don't have access to it anymore. This
  is a minor point, but that can be useful.
- I did not include `WITH-OPEN-FILE`, in case you want to read from
  something else than files (streams).
- `#'READ` is quoted, this is not important here but a good habit to have in macros, so that you actually evalute things at evaluation time, not at macroexpansion time.

### Examples

```
(with-input-from-string (in "abcdef")
  (do-read (char (in :take #'read-char) char)
    (print char)))
```

Print all characters and return `#\f`.

```
(with-input-from-string (in (format nil "~{~a~%~}" *features*))
  (let ((lines 0))
    (do-read (line in lines)
      (incf lines))))
```

Print the number of lines in a string.

Comment: This is great, thanks.

`destructuring-bind`? Very cool. Did not think to use that.

But `once-only` leaves me confused. And other people. https://common-lisp.net/project/cl-utilities/doc/once-only.html  Can you clarify?

Comment: `once-only` is like `with-gensyms` so is for macro hygiene. But ensures that the variable which is replaced by a gensym - will be executed just once in the macro body. So a very practical macro - and mostly one wants `once-only` if one uses `with-gensyms`.

Comment: There is a very nice in-depth step-by-step explanation of `once-only` here: https://malisper.me/once-only/

Comment: The function here could be any expression, and generally you do not expect an expression written once to be evaluated multiple times under the hood. So in a normal function, you just bind a temp. variable to to the expression and then use the variable. Once-only automatically adds this tmp var. This is needed here because the loop eval the expression each time.

Comment: 'You cannot mix &optional and &key' ?

Comment: Note that (although this probably can't work here since you don't know what `take` is and what its conventions are) a good EOF-detecting trick with `read` and functions with compatible arguments is `(eql (read in nil in) in)` since one value they can never return is the stream they are reading from.  This avoids potentially expensive exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

Works for me:

```
(defmacro doread ((it f &optional out &key (take #'read)) &body body)
  "Iterator for running over files or strings."
  (let ((str (gensym)))
    `(with-open-file (,str ,f)
       (loop for ,it = (funcall ,take ,str nil)
             while ,it do
             (progn ,@body))
       ,out)))

(defun para1 (f)
  "Print  everything up to first blank line. 
   Return the lines found in that way"
  (let ((lines 0))
    (doread (x f lines :take #'read-line)
      (if (equalp "" (string-trim '(#\Space #\Tab) x))
          (return)
        (and (incf lines) (format t "~a~%" x))))))
```

Using it in LispWorks:

```
CL-USER 104 > (para1 (capi:prompt-for-file "text file"))
;;; -*- mode: Lisp; Base: 10 ; Syntax: ANSI-Common-Lisp ; buffer-read-only: t; -*-
;;; This is ASDF 3.3.3: Another System Definition Facility.
;;;
;;; Feedback, bug reports, and patches are all welcome:
;;; please mail to <asdf-devel@common-lisp.net>.
;;; Note first that the canonical source for ASDF is presently
;;; <URL:http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/>.
;;;
;;; If you obtained this copy from anywhere else, and you experience
;;; trouble using it, or find bugs, you may want to check at the
;;; location above for a more recent version (and for documentation
;;; and test files, if your copy came without them) before reporting
;;; bugs.  There are usually two "supported" revisions - the git master
;;; branch is the latest development version, whereas the git release
;;; branch may be slightly older but is considered `stable'
15
```

It's just that once you want to specify `:take` you also need to provide the optional arg. That's a common pitfall and that's why the combination of optional and keyword args is not liked.